# Confidence Interval for Pivot

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**I don't follow the step highlighted in green.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\hat\theta=\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}X_k$ and that, for every $k$, $X_k\leqslant\theta$ almost surely, hence $\hat\theta\leqslant\theta$ almost surely.